# Google TalkPlugin repo disappeared in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, google-talk

Source

```
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/ stable main
```

which worked before is now (after upgrade to 16.04) failing with

```
Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/talkplugin/deb/dists/stable/Release: 
   No Hash entry in Release file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/dl.google.com_linux_talkplugin_deb_dists_stable_Release
   which is considered strong enough for security purposes
```

What repo should I use now?

Answer (score 2):

It's because google hasn't updated their repo to keep up with the [changes in apt](https://tracker.debian.org/news/755358).

The only option as fas as I know is to use the .deb which you can download [from google](https://www.google.com/tools/dlpage/hangoutplugin)

Install it with

```
sudo dpkg -i google-talkplugin_current_amd64.deb
```

or if you use the 32 bit version

```
sudo dpkg -i google-talkplugin_current_i386.deb
```